# Executar função PHP de forma assíncrona

Tags: php, async

Utilizando PHP, é possível executar uma função de forma assíncrona?

Exemplo:

O cliente(browser) faz uma requisição ao servidor, nessa requisição o PHP executa uma função assíncrona que pode demorar alguns segundos, porém antes da mesma finalizar, o servidor responde para o cliente de forma que enquanto a operação assíncrona está sendo executada, o browser não precise ficar esperando ela acabar para receber uma resposta.

Comment: Alguma das respostas lhe ajudou? Ou há problemas nelas? Comente informando ao autor qual a duvida em tentar usar a solução proposta. Se alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema, marque-a como correta clicando em ✓

Comment: O PHP 7 já tem suporte a programação assíncrona.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim, a partir de algumas bibliotecas externas é possível implementar coisas parecidas de forma bem simples.

O projeto mais conhecido é o [reactPHP](http://reactphp.org/).

Existe um benchmark bem interessante comparando o [reactPHP com nodeJS](http://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2013/11/benchmarking-codswallop-nodejs-v-php).

Comment: De onde vem a informação de que o ``reactPHP`` é o mais conhecido?

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/react/react - total de 22 mil instalações downloads pelo Packagist. Se souber de um que o ultrapasse me avise.

Comment: Mas isto incluem apenas pacotes composer. As extensões PHP ficam de fora desta contagem, certo ? Só um dos  bundles para SF2 interagir com German tem mais de 11K

Comment: Gearman é um worker de jobs, tem como objetivo "desafogar" requisições do servidor principal (exemplo: envios de emails em carga), função assíncrona é outra coisa.

Comment: Aguardo seu resumo

Comment: Calma :) Vamos ver o que eu aprenderei com esta pergunta aqui antes hehehe

Answer (score 5):

Você pode conseguir este resultado utilizando paralelismo com a extensão PHP [Gearman](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.gearman.php)

Exemplo:

```
<?php
# Criação do worker
$gmworker= new GearmanWorker();

# Adicionando um servidor (localhost é o padrão)
$gmworker->addServer();

# Registre uma função
$gmworker->addFunction("reverse", "reverse_fn");

print "Esperando resultado...\n";

while($gmworker->work())
{
  if ($gmworker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
  {
    echo "return_code: " . $gmworker->returnCode() . "\n";
    break;
  } else {
    print "Ainda esperando resultado...\n";
  }
}

function reverse_fn($job)
{
  return strrev($job->workload());
}
```

Veja [mais exemplos](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/gearman.examples.php) no manual do PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Em complento as duas respostas acima,
você pode utilizar `German` + `reactPhp`
 com o [gearman-async](https://github.com/bzikarsky/gearman-async):  "A async Gearman implementation for PHP ontop of reactphp"

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php

use Gearman\Async\ClientInterface;
use Gearman\Async\Event\TaskDataEvent;
use Gearman\Async\TaskInterface;
use Gearman\Async\Factory;

require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

// use default options
$factory = new Factory();

$factory->createClient("127.0.0.1", 4730)->then(
    // on successful creation
    function (ClientInterface $client) {
        $client->submit("reverse", "Hallo Welt!")->then(function(TaskInterface $task) {
            printf("Submitted: %s with \"%s\" [handle: %s]\n", 
                $task->getFunction(), 
                $task->getWorkload(), 
                $task->getHandle()
            );

            $task->on('complete', function (TaskDataEvent $event, ClientInterface $client) {
                echo "Result: {$event->getData()}\n";
                $client->disconnect();
            });
        });
    },
    // error-handler
    function($error) {
        echo "Error: $error\n";
    }
);

$factory->getEventLoop()->run();
```