# Guzzle e requisições assíncronas em PHP

Tags: php, guzzle

Eu estava dando uma olhada na documentação do [`GuzzleHttp`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/faq.html) e vi que lá tem uma explicação sobre como utilizá-lo para fazer requisições assíncronas.

```
$promise = $client->requestAsync('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/get');
$promise->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'Got a response! ' . $response->getStatusCode();
});
```

Eu fiz alguns testes exatamente como no exemplo, e não obtive o retorno esperado. A `Closure` que é o argumento de `then` não funciona.

Como funciona essa requisições assíncronas no `Guzzle`?

Existe alguma maneira de fazê-las em PHP (como se faz em Ajax), ou é outra história (os conceitos são diferentes)?

Comment: Normalmente a técnica usada é executar um comando shell. No seu caso, pode ser que a referida biblioteca tenha algum bug ou não esteja conseguindo detectar o sistema operacional corretamente para aplicar um comando adequado. O comando varia ente distribuições Linux e também Windows. Verifique se não é esse o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Até aonde sei PHP não suporta eventos assíncronos *nativamente*, justamente porque ele é síncrono, ou seja ele é uma camada de *requisição* e *resposta* e não vejo tanta necessidade de executar dois eventos ao mesmo tempo.

Sobre o seu problema talvez seja a falta do `wait();`, a documentação do Guzzle fala que o uso é com [PSR-7](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/) assim:

```
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/get');
$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});
$promise->wait();
```

de qualquer maneira para o front-end isto será imperceptível e para o servidor eu não vejo a "vantagem" do uso disto, pois a camada maior do script ainda terá que esperar os eventos terminarem (quando usar `wait();`).

Não sei quais meios eles usam, mas se quer estudar sobre o assunto existe o:

> - http://php.net/pthreads
> - Download windows: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/
>
> <sub>https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872965/1518921</sub>
>
> Também tem o reactPHP como dito aqui [Executar função PHP de forma assíncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27403/3635)

### Async hack (hhvm)

Na linguagem hack (hhvm) existem métodos assíncronos:

- http://docs.hhvm.com/hack/async/introduction

No entanto para a resposta você não irá sentir mudanças (acredito eu), mas no back-end é como se fosse mais de um Thread e assim pode executar mais de uma tarefa sem esperar outra, exemplo (só funciona com `<?hh`):

```
<?hh

namespace Hack\UserDocumentation\Async\Intro\Examples\Limtations;

async function do_cpu_work(): Awaitable<void> {
  print("Start CPU work\n");
  $a = 0;
  $b = 1;

  $list = [$a, $b];

  for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i) {
    $c = $a + $b;
    $list[] = $c;
    $a = $b;
    $b = $c;
  }
  print("End CPU work\n");
}

async function do_sleep(): Awaitable<void> {
  print("Start sleep\n");
  sleep(1);
  print("End sleep\n");
}

async function main(): Awaitable<void> {
  print("Start of main()\n");
  await \HH\Asio\v([
    do_cpu_work(),
    do_sleep(),
  ]);
  print("End of main()\n");
}

\HH\Asio\join(main());
```

### PHP CLI

Uma alternativa seria executar um comando como se fosse no terminal e esperar ou não a resposta lembrando o `async`, eu fiz isto para um caso bem especifico, aonde existia um script que ao processar consumia bastante o Apache, então usando `exec` fiz algo assim:

- Windows, deve-se executar algo como:

  ```
  set QUERY_STRING="foo=1&bar=2"
  start /B cmd /S /C php -c php.ini c:/wamp/www/arquivo.php
  ```

  O `start /B cmd /S /C` é pra esperar o comando terminar.
- Like-Unix, deve-se executar algo como:

  ```
   export QUERY_STRING="foo=1&bar=2";
   php -c php.ini "/etc/www/arquivo.php";
  ```

O script todo ficou assim (note que fiz este script a algum tempo, se falhar me avise):

```
function async($phpScript, $query_string='') {
    $php_exe = 'php';

    $iniFile = php_ini_loaded_file();

    if (false === $iniFile) {
        echo 'Erro ao carregar php.ini not loaded (php_ini_loaded_file = false)';
        exit;
    } else if (false === file_exists($phpScript)) {
        echo 'Script não econtrado: ' . $phpScript;
        exit;
    }

    $output = array();
    $exec = '';

    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'WIN') !== false) {
        foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
            if ($key !== 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' && $key !== 'QUERY_STRING') {
                $exec .= 'set ' . $key . '=' . escapeshellcmd($value) . '& ';
            }
        }

        $exec .= 'set QUERY_STRING=' . escapeshellcmd($query_string) . '& ';
        $exec .= 'start /B cmd /S /C php ' . escapeshellcmd(' -c ' . $iniFile . ' ' . $phpScript);
    } else {
        foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
            if ($key !== 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' && $key !== 'QUERY_STRING') {
                $exec .= 'export ' . $key . '=' . escapeshellarg($value) . '; ';
            }
        }

        $exec .= 'export QUERY_STRING=' . escapeshellarg($query_string) . '; ';
        $exec .= 'php -c ' . escapeshellarg($iniFile) . ' ' .
                    escapeshellarg($phpScript);// . ' >/dev/null 2>&1 &';
    }

    exec($exec, $output, $status);

    return array(
        'status' => $status,
        'command' => $exec,
        'output'  => $output
    );
}
```

Eu comentei o `>/dev/null 2>&1 &` pois no Debian6 (na época) tive algum problema, mas pode usa-lo no terminal assim:

```
 export QUERY_STRING="foo=1&bar=2";
 php -c php.ini "/etc/www/arquivo.php" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Isto não é bem "assíncrono" para o script, mas é possível executar arquivos que consomem mais memória sem afetar o Apache e Ngnix por exemplo, pois ele é executado separadamente, sei que não é bem o que pediu, mas não tenho certeza de qual é realmente a sua necessidade.

Comment: Preciso  fazer várias requisições em um webservice (o que é lento) sem que afete na velocidade de carregamento da página. Imaginei que realmente não tivesse como deixar o "php assíncrono", queria mesmo era entender qual era o objetivo do guzzle fazer isso.  Acho que vale a pena olhar as Threads

Comment: @WallaceMaxters com async ou sem a velocidade de entrega para o cliente-side é a mesma, a única melhora será se quiser correr dois webservices em uma requisição, mas provavelmente o consumo de memoria ou processador irá aumentar. Estas soluções de async nem sempre são necessárias. Se tiver algum problema com o I/O pois uma página que esta carregando um webservice trava outras requisições leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57827/3635