# Várias funções php ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php

Tenho um script que contém inúmeras funções.
Todas independentes umas das outras.
Está demorando um tempo considerável para executar todas as funções.

Existe uma maneira de executar várias funções sem esperar que a anterior acabe ? Ou executá-las em paralelo ?

Por exemplo:

```
<?php

   function ajustar_titulos(){
      for($x=0;$x<999999;$x++) //to do
   }

   function ajustar_enderecos(){
      for($x=0;$x<999999;$x++) //to do
   }

   function indexar(){
      for($x=0;$x<999999;$x++) //to do
   }

   ajustar_titulos();
   ajustar_enderecos();
   indexar();
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27401/executar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php-de-forma-ass%C3%ADncrona

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é o uso de I/O assíncrono não bloqueante, que é popular por ser usado em NodeJS e Javascript. Essa forma de processamento permite iniciar operações de escrita ou leitura simultaneamente em uma única thread. Hoje existem bibliotecas em PHP que facilitam o uso dessa abordagem. Uma delas é a Amp que eu escolhi para usar de exemplo por causa do suporte à requisições HTTP, banco de dados e a simplicidade da API.

Exemplo:

```
?php                                                                                                                                                                                                              

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';                                                                                                                                                                          

use Amp\Loop;                                                                                                                                                                                                      
use Amp\Artax\Request;                                                                                                                                                                                             
use Amp\Artax\DefaultClient;                                                                                                                                                                                       

/**                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 * Faz uma requisição assíncrona em alguma das APIs que integramos                                                                                                                                                 
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 * @param string $url URL alvo da requisição HTTP                                                                                                                                                                  
 * @param string $listKey Chave do objeto retornado que contém os itens                                                                                                                                            
 * @param string $jokeKey Chave dos itens que contém a piada                                                                                                                                                       
 * @return Amp\Promise Representa o resultado da operação assíncrona                                                                                                                  
 */                                                                                                                                                                                                                
function requestApi($url, $listKey, $jokeKey) {                                                                                                                                                                    
    // A função Amp\call converte um generator em uma promise, dentro dela e da Loop::run                                                                                                                          
    // as instruções yield esperam pela resposta de uma promise. Durante essa espera o
    // loop de eventos vai estar trabalhando em outros códigos, assim evitando
    // o bloqueio do processo                                                                                                                                                           
    return Amp\call(function () use ($url, $listKey, $jokeKey) {                                                                                                                                                   
        $client = new DefaultClient;                                                                                                                                                                               
        $request = (new Request($url))->withHeader('Accept', 'application/json');                                                                                                                                  
        $response = yield $client->request($request); // Até aqui o objeto contém apenas os headers HTTP                                                                                                       
        $json = json_decode(yield $response->getBody(), true);                                                                                                                                                     
        return array_column($json[$listKey], $jokeKey);                                                                                                                                                            
    });                                                                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

/**                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 * A função Loop:run gerencia o código assíncrono e permite que yield seja usado para aguardar                                                                                                                     
 * o retorno das operações                                                                                                                                                                                           
 */                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Loop::run(function () {                                                                                                                                                                                            
    // Enviar um array para o yield faz com que as requisições sejam feitas simultaneamente!
    $jokeResults = yield [                                                                                                                                                                                         
        'dad' => requestApi('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term=food', 'results', 'joke'),                                                                                                                     
        'chuckNorris' => requestApi('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=food', 'result', 'value'),                                                                                                      
    ];
    // Por causa do "yield" o array joke results vai conter o resultado das requisições, que são
    // algumas piadas aleatórias. 
    foreach (array_merge($jokeResults['dad'], $jokeResults['chuckNorris']) as $joke) {                                                                                                                             
        echo "$joke\n";                                                                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
});
```

Você consegue resolver isso com Ajax também, que por padrão já é assíncrono.